# For any given function, drawn on Cartesian coorinates, is there a way to calculate the length of it between any particular interval of $x$?

Tags: calculus

For *any* given function, drawn on Cartesian coordinates, is there a way to calculate the length of it between any given interval of $x$? From $0$ to $5$ say.

Comment: With suitable interpretation of "any": no

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going to try and solve that problem.  Now I know I shouldn't bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function. If you want the arc length of $f(x)$ for $x$ from $a$ to $b$ you will have to evaluate the integral

$$\int_a^b{\sqrt{1+(\frac{df}{dx})^2}}dx$$